# Hebrew language not showing - Android

Tags: android, string

I have created 2 string files one the default under `res/values/strings.xml` and the other under `res/values-he/strings.xml`. I am opening my app, while the os is configured to be in Hebrew, but still I see the values of the default strings which are in English. Is there any thing more to do?

**Note:** in the eclipse graphical layout editor I can choose Hebrew and see that it works fine.

Here is some of my default strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="app_name">MyApp</string>
<string name="title_activity_splash">MyApp</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="title_activity_login">Login</string>
<string name="email">Email</string>
<string name="password">Password</string>
<string name="forgot_password">Forgot password?</string>
<string name="sign_up">Sign up</string>
<string name="login">Login</string> 
.
.
.
```

and here is **all** (for now) my hebrew strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="action_settings">הגדרות</string>
    <string name="hello_world">שלום עולם</string>
    <string name="email">דואל</string>
    <string name="password">סיסמא</string>
    <string name="forgot_password">שכחת סיסמא</string>
    <string name="sign_up">רישום</string>
    <string name="login">התחברות</string>


</resources>
```

Here it in eclipse:

[image]

here it on the device (device os in hebrew):

[image]

Comment: 4.1.1 checked both on emulator of genymotion and real devices.

Comment: Other staff, like google map copyright on the bottom of the map (I use it in my app) is in hebrew, but my strings aren't. WHY??!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, you correctly have:

```
res/values/strings.xml
```

and

```
res/values-he/strings.xml
```

With the correct structure, be also sure that the strings have the **very same names in each strings.xml file**, or the trick won't work.

The **missing strings** in a translation file **won't be translated** and the default strings (from res/values/strings.xml) will be used instead.

For hebrew, in particular, on some devices **values-he** is recognized. in some others it's **values-iw**.
So, make a copy of values-he and name it values-iw. Keep both in your structure.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong in my question, I did as you wrote here, I am fixing the question.

Comment: The string names are the same in the `he` strings.xml there are less strings then in the default one.

Comment: I edited my answer to be more useful (just to clarify that the **string names must be identical**)

Comment: So - the missing strings won't be translated and the default strings will be used instead.

Comment: Yes I know, but no string is translated. I have added a note to the question.

Comment: That's so strange. I use 5 languages, 5... and it works - I even change them "on the fly". And it still works. Please double check that you don'thave some little mismatch in string names, like misplaced _ or spaces. Or a plural in a name (things that tend to run away from our eyes).

Comment: More wired is that I have a google map in my app and when on hebrew all the google text is in hebrew (copyrights). I am totally lost.

Comment: I'm not aware of Google Maps, but I guess that it gets its results from Internet. So, no wonder that the contents are properly provided in the correct language you asked it to send you the results.

Comment: I have added the string.xml files.

Comment: They seem to be perfectly aligned. Apart those strings you don't need or want to be translated. So, just correct. Now, I don't know if (but I would expect that, of course, yes) Robot font supports the Hebrew characters or if it has to be set a different encoding than UTF-8? UTF-16? or UTF-32? But this is just a speculation, since I finished my ideas. It really should work as it is... :O

Comment: Did you test it on both a PHYSICAL and an EMULATED device? No matter if it doesn't work well on an emulator... it's more important that it works on real devices. We're used to emulators imperfections, after all... I mean **running**, not just the graphical editor.

Comment: it is not working on any device, nor emulator. I have 2 devices and infinite number of emulators... dang it!

Comment: Tried to clean Your Projekt?

Comment: The mystery is deeper and deeper... Make a different trial - just for fun - use a language different from Hebrew: French, Spanish, Italian, German, ... (you can use google translator - no matter if it's not perfect). Just to try (respectively: values-fr, values-es, values-it, values-de)

Comment: Maybe I found an answer... on some devices **values-he** is recognized. in some others it's **values-iw**.  Make a copy of values-he and name it values-iw. Keep both folders.

Comment: What happens if you rename it to values-fr and set the emulator to French?

Comment: You were right!!! iw worked!!! (This hebrew language took me as long as it exists to fix it (5000 years or so)...

Answer (score 2):

What solved the problem for me was to use the folder `values-iw`.